# Update razor variable in a angular conditional div properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am wondering if I can update a razor variable in a conditional div(with ng-if) in it. Something Like bellow code

```
@{
   var db = "Test1";
 }
<div ng-if="vm.IsLoggedIn">
        @{db = "Test2";}
</div>
<div ng-if="vm.HasAuthorizedUser">
        @{db = "Test3";}
</div>
```

After updating the variable i will send it to the another partial view while doing `Html.RenderPartial` in a new `ViewDataDictionary`.

Problem statement - this evaluation of variable `db` is done when the `vm` is not ready I thing because when i checked it goes into both div without worrying about `ng-if`and set the variable with last assigned value . Means in this case i will get `db=Test3` every time.

I know some work around to resolve the final problem , but i want to resolve the problem by this approach.

Thanks in advance

Comment: MVC Razor code is execute server-side to help generate the HTML. Angular code is client-side javascript which uses the generated HTML, so all the razor code is run first. What your code is actually doing is creating a .NET variable called `db`, setting it to 3 different things -
 ultimately it will always be `"Test3"` - then outputting 2 empty divs to the client. To set `db` to the correct value, you will need to check if the user is logged in etc. in .NET code.

Comment: as @Rhumborl pointed out... you either move your condition on your variable `db` to the client side or... move the `ng-if` to an `if` within your view. Another Idea is to assign the `db` variable directly on the backend of your controller and have that as part of your model. Seems that `isLoggedIn` or `hasAuthorizedUser` could be generated somewhere in your backend first.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, i will follow some other path for it.